# Slick Slider - Save images on mobile by holding the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, slick.js

I am using [SlickSlider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (which is an amazing slider) for my gallery page of my site.

However I am having an issue only on mobile.
When a user clicks and holds an image on mobile, The option to save the image never appears (only mobile)

I was looking into some timeout functions on mouseover but I have not had any luck with that.

You can see a similar example of what I am doing here on this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Zlerp/pen/MVWyYd)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="gallery-slider">
     <div>
       <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div>
       <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div>
       <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" alt="">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.gallery-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

add to `img` elements in css:

```
  -webkit-touch-callout: default;
  -webkit-user-select: default;
  -khtml-user-select: default;
  -moz-user-select: default;
  -ms-user-select: default;
  user-select: default;
```